# Using ng-clip, how do I add content to the clipboard form code (rather than declaratively in markup)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zeroclipboard

Thanks for looking.  I am implementing ng-clip in my project successfully for various tasks such as copying a value to the clipboard when a user clicks a button.  Of course this is handled declaratively like so:

```
<a clip-click-fallback="CopyStuff()" clip-copy="ModelToBeCopied">Foo</a>
```

I now have a need to add an item to the clipboard from the Angular controller, specifically, a string that is returned from the server in a call back function:

```
$scope.Callback = function(response){

//How do I copy the response to the clip board??

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-clip` is a directive that uses ZeroClipboard, a flash based solution. You can't use `ng-clip` in a controller. Copying to the clipboard without user interaction is a general Javascript challenge, not one specific to Angular.

See this question for possible solutions: [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)